# How to create a rails button with an icon and text?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-helpers

How would you create this button using a rail helper?

```
<button type="submit" class="btn">
 Create My Account <i class="fa"></i>
</button>
```

So far I have

```
<%= f.submit "Create My Account", :class => "btn" %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `button` form helper and pass it a block.

```
<%= f.button class: 'btn' do %>
  Create My Account <i class="fa"></i>
<% end %>
```

See more at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-button

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails

Here you will get answer of your quesiton.

```
<%=f.submit (fa_icon "camera-retro", text: "Take a photo"), class: "btn" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
<%= f.submit "Create My Account <i class=\"fa\"></i>", :class => "btn" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

there are many options:-

```
        <%= f.submit (‘<i class=“fa fa-thumbs-up fa-lg”> </i>’).html_safe,:class=>"btn "%>

    --------------------------------------------------------------------

        <%= button_to update_users_path, {remote: true, class: "btn btn-small"} do %>
             Submit <i class="fa-save fa-md"></i>    
        <% end %>

    --------------------------------------------------------

        <%= button_tag( :class => "button_black") do %>
                Submit Details <i class="fa fa-reset fa-md"></i>
        <% end %>
```

Comment: Your second option gives the following error: syntax error, unexpected keyword_class, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '(' ...mit (Create Account ‘<i class=“fa fa-save fa-lg”> </i>... ... ^

Comment: Why the `remote: true` on the second example?

Comment: @spuggy  just in case if you want a ajax call...that's why...you can remove it .

Answer (score 0):

5 different ways of doing it have already been given. I prefer:

```
<%= f.submit :class => "btn" do %>
  Create My Account <i class="fa"></i>"
<% end %>
```

I think its the cleanest.